# I see that I'm missing something. What am I doing wrong? Troubles with cucumber and regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber

```
When /I (un)?check the following items: (.*)/ do |uncheck, items_list|
  items_list.split(/,\s?/).each do |item|
    step %Q{I #{uncheck}check "items_#{item.gsub! /"/, ''}"}
  end
end
```

I have a check and uncheck step defined in another file that works great
if in my feature I call

```
When I check the following items: "A,B,C"
```

it works

if I call

```
When I uncheck the following items: "D,E,F"
```

it happens that cucumber tryes to uncheck 'items_' <<-- ??? why this doesn't contain D, E or F???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove the bang "!" from:

```
step %Q{I #{uncheck}check "items_#{item.gsub! /"/, ''}"}
```

Use:

```
step %Q{I #{uncheck}check "items_#{item.gsub /"/, ''}"}
```

Or better:

```
When /I (un)?check the following items: (.*)/ do |uncheck, items_list|
  items_list.gsub! /"/, ''
  items_list.split(/,\s?/).each do |item|
    step %Q{I #{uncheck}check "items_#{item}"}
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks, that worked but I can't understand why, can you explain?

Comment: first, String.gsub! returns nil. So you can't use it the way you was doing.

And removing the quotation marks first in items_list.gsub! /"/, '' seems to be nicer than trying to remove every time.

If you have trouble with regular expressions, I recommend you take a look at http://rubular.com.